# How to call a method that returns a list in another method and delete items in this list using iterator

Tags: java, playframework

Hey guys am new to this and I would appreciate any help.

I want to call getListTenant() from my save function below and clear the list using iterator before doing my save. Below is the code in my controller:

```
package controllers;

public class TenantController extends AppController {

    Tenant tenant;
    FacilityUnit unit;

    // list tenants in selected facility
    public Result listTenant() {

        return ok(Json.toJson(getTenantList()));
    }


        private  List<Tenant> getTenantList() {

            List<Tenant> tenants = Tenant.find
                .fetch("unit.facility")
                .where().eq("unit.facility", currentFacility())
                .findList();
            return tenants;
        }

    public Result saveTenant() {
        JsonNode submissionNode = request().body().asJson();
        JsonNode itemsArray = submissionNode.get("items");
        //clear tenant


      // create the new tenant
        if (itemsArray.isArray()) {

            for (JsonNode itemNode : itemsArray) {
                JsonNode tenantNode = itemNode.get("tenant");
                String tenantId = tenantNode.get("id").asText();
                JsonNode unitNode = itemNode.get("unit");
                String unitId = unitNode.get("id").asText();

                System.out.println("##### Tenant ID IS " + tenantId);
                System.out.println("##### unit ID IS " + unitId);

                // Tenant.find.where().eq("tenant.id",
                // tenant.getTenant().getId()).eq("unit.id", unit.getId()
                // ).delete();
                // Util.isNotEmpty() &&
                if (Util.isNotEmpty(tenantId) && Util.isNotEmpty(unitId)) {
                    // these two are the minimal criteria for an tenant

                    Tenant tenant = new Tenant();
                    tenant.setTenant(Person.find.byId(tenantId));
                    tenant.setUnit(FacilityUnit.find.byId(unitId));

                    tenant.save();
                    System.out.println("##### SAVED A TENANT");
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("##### DONE");
        return ok(infoMessage("Update of " + tenant.getTenant() + "successful"));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the `Tenants` from `getTenantList()` and call `delete()` on them to clear them.

For example:

```
private List<Tenant> getTenantList() {
    List<Tenant> tenants = Tenant.find
        .fetch("unit.facility")
        .where().eq("unit.facility", currentFacility())
        .findList();
    return tenants;
}

public Result saveTenant() {
    // Do something...
    // ...

    // Get the tenants list that we want to clear before saving.
    // Best way to do this is loop over it and call delete.
    for (Tenant tenant : getTenantList()) {
        tenant.delete();
    }

    // Do some more things...
    // ...
}
```